# can I detect slow device in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm making a phonegap application that has a page slide function. It works fine on fast devices, but on slow devices it's laggy and gives users a bad experience, so I have made a version that's not as pretty, but it works better on slow devices.

Now my problem is, that I can't find a way to detect whether or not the device is slow. I can probably check the api version on android, but old samsungs are running 4.2.2, so it wont do the trick.

So how can I detect a slow device in phonegap?

cheers

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?